# Error Deserializing object after API returns 400

Tags: c#, json, api

I did a lot of googling here with no luck.

Here is the code:

```
try
        {
            response = client.PostAsync("", content).Result;  // Blocking call! Program will wait here until a response is received or a timeout occurs.

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var contents = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                FxRateReturn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FedExFreightQuoteAPI_inbound.Root>(contents);


            }
            else
            {
                var contents = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                FxRateReturn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FedExFreightQuoteAPI_inbound.Root>(contents);
                throw new Exception("Error retrurned by the API: \n" + response.StatusCode.ToString() + response.ReasonPhrase.ToString() + FxRateReturn.errors.FirstOrDefault().message);
            }

            return FxRateReturn; 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
        }
```

now the error is actually happening in Else clause when the reponse.IsSuccessStatusCode is false.

The response.Content does not appear to have JSON in it and I get this error message: ERROR: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 0, position 0.

I did test this WITH Postman and the response is indeed there in JSON. I just don't know how to get it as it is obviously different when a different response is returned :(

Now debugging this I dit notice that it gets converted to some weird set of characters and it indeed is not JSON. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my code for the declarations so that you know what objects I am using:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(APIURL + "/rate/v1/rates/quotes");

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", p_Token);


        //Dictionary<string, string> values;

        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p_FedExOutbound), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); 
        HttpResponseMessage response;
```

Comment: When you get an error (not 200 ok) then body of the message is empty which is what gets serlialized/deserialized.  To prevent error only deserialize when the response is 200 OK.

Comment: unrelated to the json problem, but: stop using `.Result`; the correct thing to do is to `await` the operation; now; what is `contents`? what are the headers? is this an accept-encoding thing? is there a `Content-Encoding` header on the response? (and if so: what is it?) what is the `Content-Type` header?

Comment: @Be05x5 You have to show your API, since your API try to validate data and I guess it does it in a wrong way. And if you don't cooperate your question will be closed as needing some more details.

Comment: I apologize for not commenting earlier here! I got carried away with another project! Anyways I am expecting a return JSON from FedEx API when there is an error, which will give me a more detailed error message other than just APIU Returned error general kind of a message! Hence I was confused! What other code do you need to see here?

Answer (score 0):

you probably using an API controller and the data in your request body is not valid. In this case exception 400 returns immediately, before the request get inside of the action. Your code should be expecting this case

```
}
else 
{
var statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString()
var errorMessage= response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
               
throw new Exception("Error retrurned by the API: \n" + statusCode+ "\n" + errorMessage;
}
```

if you want to return your own validation messages,  you will have to remove all validation attributes from the class properties (like Required or Range for example) or remove fluent validation from EF and use your own validation code .Or just remove [ApiController]  attribute but in this case you will have lost a lots of features.

Comment: This is fine and this is what I am doing. I was however expecting a return JSON back from the API. The actual error message returned by the API gives me the reason why it didn't work for example this is a FedEx freight quoting API and when I type a zip code in Texas but pick wrong state it should tell me wrong address error or something like that!